# Apache Camel in Payara: Lookup failed for 'java:/TransactionManager'

Tags: java, apache-camel, glassfish, payara, apache-camel-cdi

I want to use Apache Camel in a war project that is deployed to a Payara server, but once I add the camel-cdi jar to the project, deploying the application fails with

> Exception while deploying the app [TheProject-1.0-SNAPSHOT] : JNDI lookup failed for the resource: Name: [java:module/env/org.apache.camel.cdi.transaction.JtaTransactionPolicy/transactionManager], Lookup: [java:/TransactionManager], Type: [java.lang.String]
>   javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:/TransactionManager'

What are my options here? Is there a way to fix this JNDI issue or is it feasible to use Camel without CDI? I'm not doing anything that would actually need a TransactionManager.

I don't want to add Spring dependencies.

I'm using Payara 5.191 and tried Camel 2.23.1 and 3.0.0-M1.

Full stacktrace

```
  Exception while deploying the app [RegistrationInterfaceProxy-1.0-SNAPSHOT] : JNDI lookup failed for the resource: Name: [java:module/env/org.apache.camel.cdi.transaction.JtaTransactionPolicy/transactionManager], Lookup: [java:/TransactionManager], Type: [java.lang.String]
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:/TransactionManager' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound to name java:/TransactionManager]
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:496)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:442)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.ResourceValidator.validateJNDIRefs(ResourceValidator.java:891)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.ResourceValidator.validateResources(ResourceValidator.java:742)
        at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.util.ResourceValidator.event(ResourceValidator.java:146)
        at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepare(ApplicationLifecycle.java:416)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:558)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:552)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.InstanceDeployCommand.execute(InstanceDeployCommand.java:223)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:553)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:552)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:583)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:575)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:574)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1483)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:119)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1865)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1741)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.executeCommand(CommandResource.java:409)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.admin.CommandResource.execCommandMultInMultOut(CommandResource.java:258)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor210.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:148)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:200)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:103)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:104)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:272)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:268)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:298)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:268)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:256)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:704)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:377)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.JerseyContainerCommandService$3.service(JerseyContainerCommandService.java:179)
        at org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:192)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:520)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:217)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:208)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:208)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:524)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:90)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound to name java:/TransactionManager
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:761)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:735)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:167)
        at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:476)
        ... 83 more
```

Comment: What version of Camel and Payara do you use, and can you update your question with the full stacktrace.

Comment: @ClausIbsen I added the missing information

Comment: In payara is TransactionManager located in pretty non standart location `java:appserver/TransactionManager`. I havent tried it, but it should be possible to create alias to `java:/TransactionManager` using `resource-ref` in `web.xml`

Comment: Or if you really dont need container managed transactions, you can use `metadata-complete="true"` in your `web.xml`, which will efectively ignore injection of `java:/TransactionManager` in `camel-cdi` library.  `<web-app version="3.1" metadata-complete="true"></web-app>`.

Comment: @Bedla If you post your comments as an answer I will accept it. The resource-ref in web.xml worked, I will try the other thing on Friday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the TransactionManager available under the expected name, the following code needs to be added to the `web.xml`

```
<ejb-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>java:/TransactionManager</ejb-ref-name>
    <mapped-name>java:appserver/TransactionManager</mapped-name>
</ejb-ref>
```